# PHP - If condition with **AND** is not working within foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, pdo

I want to update array data which comes in foreach loop. I am trying with script given bellow, it is only updating the very last row of data.

And it is giving the error in this line `if ($updateInvoiceAddedItems AND $updateInvoiceSubtractedItems)`  .

**PHP script**

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

foreach($_POST['data'] as $key => $value) {
    $invoiceItemId = intval($value['invoiceItemId']);
    $itemId = intval($value['ItemId']);
    $QTY = intval($value['QTY']);
    $addedQTY = intval($value['addedQTY']);
    $subtractedQty = intval($value['subtractedQty']);
    $Total = is_numeric($value['total']) ? $value['total'] : false;

    try {

        if($addedQTY > 0) {
            $updateInvoiceAddedItems = $db - > prepare("UPDATE `invoiceItems` SET 
            qty = qty + : addedQTY,
            addedQty = addedQty + : addingQTY where id = : Iid ");

            $updateInvoiceAddedItems - > execute(array(':Iid' => $itemId, ':addedQTY' => $addedQTY, ':addingQTY' => $addedQty));

        }
        elseif($subtractedQty > 0) {
            $updateInvoiceSubtractedItems = $db - > prepare("UPDATE `invoiceItems`  SET 
            qty = qty - : subtractedQty,
            subtractedQty = subtractedQty + : subtractingQty where id = : iiId ");

            $updateInvoiceSubtractedItems - > execute(array(':iiId' => $itemId, ':subtractedQty' => $subtractedQty, ':subtractingQty' => $subtractedQty));


        }

        if ($updateInvoiceAddedItems AND $updateInvoiceSubtractedItems) {
            echo ' <script> alert("success") </script>';
            exit;

        } else {
            echo ' <script> alert("Error") </script>';
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Connection failed: '.$e - > getMessage();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Use `&&` instead of `AND` in your condition

Comment: `&&` or `AND` should not make a difference here. However, the variables you are comparing are undefined if the conditions are not met. And why do you want to check these PDO objects exactly? And what is `$sub_invoiceItems`? You probably want `$updateInvoiceSubtractedItems`.

Comment: @SamSwift웃 i have changed AND to && but it is still giving error in this line.

Comment: Use the suggestion by @jeroen - my answer was merely what I have done in the past and experience, his comment seems a LOT more on the money

Comment: How do you know that it updates only the last row. I mean if an error is generated it would stop your script in the first loop.

Comment: Am I missing something, in that does anyone know what the actual "error" is?

Comment: @JustBaron **1.only updating the very last row of data**  2. giving the error in this line ``if ($updateInvoiceAddedItems AND $updateInvoiceSubtractedItems)``

Comment: You have "if" "elseif", where's the "else"? You're probably not getting a value that matches the if/else statements and it's throwing an error at that line because you have no variable set. Provide an actual error that's being thrown. And yes, please use &&.

Comment: @Darius - can you give an example of that What will be the else statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question follow @Darius Answer And for the 2nd question change input name from `name="data['+i+'][name]"` to `name="data[<?php echo $i; ?>][name]"`

Answer (score 1):

Consider this, you have

```
if($addedQTY > 0) {

}elseif($subtractedQty > 0) {

}
```

What happens if you submit a form with

`$addedQty = 0`, and `$subtractedQty = 0` ?

There's nothing to set `$updateInvoiceAddedItems && $updateInvoiceSubtractedItems`

You get an error because those variables don't exist after the if() else() statement.

So it should look like :

```
if($addedQTY > 0) {
        //code
}elseif($subtractedQty > 0) {
        //code
}else{
  // throw error or something because it's not what you expected.
}

// Then do the 
if ($updateInvoiceAddedItems AND $updateInvoiceSubtractedItems) { 
  //code
}
```

OR you could do

```
if (isset($updateInvoiceAddedItems) && isset($updateInvoiceSubtractedItems)) { 
  //code
}
```

Also.. I think your && should be an "OR" statement so "||" ?

Comment: thanks @Darius - Now it is not giving error in if statement, but the first problem still exists. **It is only updating the very last row of data**.

Comment: The only reason that could be is the $_POST having wrong ID sent. Upload what a var_dump($_POST) looks like.